# Как отследить вставку ссылки в поле и выполнять ajax?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть текстовое поле в которое вводится ссылка. После чего выполняется AJAX запрос на получение странице по ссылке.
Сложность в том, что событие keyup реагирует на каждое изменение поля, даже при ctrl+v, запрос выполняется 3 раза.
Как сделать, чтобы после корректно введенное ссылки - один раз выполнился запрос ajax?

Comment: Хм, а как вы определяете корректность ссылки?

Все 3 ссылки например могут быть корректны

http://site.ru/
http://site.ru/catalog
http://site.ru/catalog/123

Может следует по нажатию на enter проверять корректность ссылки а не при каждом нажатии клавиши?

Comment: Нужно без нажатия, как это сделано в VK, FB

Comment: В vk сейчас посмотрел он реагирует на пробел после url, вставку или enter, а также возможно отложенный по времени запрос. Покажите свой код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутри обработчика проверяйте, что поле содержит валидный нрл, и только тогда отправляйте запрос

Comment: Сделал, но при вставке в input, почему-то 2 запроса аякс выполняются

Comment: чтоб два раза не отправляло, попробуйте такой шаблон:
    
    var send = (function () {
      var httpRequestAlredySend = false;
      return function (data) {
        if (!httpRequestAlredySend) {
          httpRequestAlredySend = true;
          //send request
        }
      }
    }());

Используя ф-ю send вы можете сделать только один запрос.

Answer (score 1):

Используй обработчик события change или сделай отложенный обработчик на основе keyup + setTimeout (сбрасывая таймаут при след. нажатии клавиши).

Comment: Можно пример?

Comment: как-то так

    var timeout_id;

    $('input').on('keyup', function(){
        if (timeout_id) {
           clearTimeout(timeout_id);
        }
        timeout_id = setTimeout(function(){
          ...
        }, 250);
    });

Comment: Это не решит проблему с ctrl+v например,его запросто можно нажать длиннее чем за 250мс. По нормальному там бы надо еще ловить keydown и сравнивать изменилось ли в реальности value, но это страшный геморой.

onchange нормальный выход, но он срабатывает только после блюра из поля.

Тут можно использовать биндинги и какой нибудь knockout, angular и так далее но это уже совсем другая история, и ради одного поля не имеет смысла

Comment: ок, вынести общий кусок кода в отдельную функцию, а в обработчики событий добавить это: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript

Comment: Там по идее не только ctrl надо фильтровать, а все клавиши не меняющие содержимое поля, стрелочки наприме, на них ведь тоже сработает keyup

Comment: еще есть событие input ну и да, откладывать  всё равно надо, причем подобный запрос я бы вообще на секнду откладывал.

Answer (score 0):

Как я уже говорил в комментариях, выполняем запрос только если была вставка/изменение textarea, а также после пробела или enter при вводе с клавиатуры, код грубоват, но работает.

```
Url = {
    patternKeyUp: /(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])(\s{1,}|\n) ?/,
    urlPattern: /(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])/g,
    foundUrl: null,

    checkUrl: function( url, pattern ) {
        var checkUrl = pattern.test( url );
        if ( checkUrl ) {
            var urls = url.match(this.urlPattern);
            if ( this.foundUrl != urls[0]) {
                this.foundUrl = urls[0];
                alert("Send to "+this.foundUrl);
            }
        }
    }
}
$("textarea").on("paste change", function( e ) {
     setTimeout( function() {
            var str = $("textarea").val();
            Url.checkUrl(str, Url.urlPattern);
     }, 50);   
} );
$("textarea").on("keyup", function( e ) {
    var str = $(this).val();
    Url.checkUrl(str, Url.patternKeyUp);
} );
```